# How many Queries per second is normal for this site?

Tags: performance, load

I have a small site running Flynax classifieds software. I get 10/15 users concurrent users at the most. Sometimes I get very high load avg that results in outages and downtime problems on my server.

I run

```
root@host [~]# mysqladmin proc stat
```

and I see this :

```
Uptime: 111346  Threads: 2  Questions: 22577216  Slow queries: 5159  Opens: 395  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 285  Queries per second avg: 202.766
```

Are 202.766 queries per second is normal for a small site like mine ?!

The hosting company is saying, my app is poorly coded and must be optimized.

The Flynax developers are saying, the server is poor and weak and must be replaced.

I'm not sure what to do? any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

202.766 queries per second isn't normals for small website you described.
Probably some queries run in a loop and that is why you have such statistics.

As far as I know the latest flynax versions has mysql debug option, using this option
you can see how many queries run on the page and how much time each query executes.

Cheers